# Uncaught TypeError: P.addInstancingSupport is not a function [autodesk-forge]

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

This morning I started getting this error when I try to display the model in my viewer, the code was working fine till last night. Upon looking into details, I see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: P.addInstancingSupport is not a function
at Aa (viewer3D.min.js:14)
at a.initialize (viewer3D.min.js:14)
at a.e.initialize (viewer3D.min.js:19)
at a.initialize (viewer3D.min.js:21)
at a.e.start (viewer3D.min.js:19)
at d.selectItem (viewer3D.min.js:21)
at onDocumentLoadSuccess (ForgeViewer.js:45)
at viewer3D.min.js:21
at j (viewer3D.min.js:20)
at XMLHttpRequest.p (viewer3D.min.js:4)
```

The error seems to be stemming from 'viewer3D.min.js'. I am fairly new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the Viewer are you using? You can run LMV_VIEWER_VERSION from your console in Chrome Dev Tools. If the version is "1.X" you might want to check this https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/view-and-data-api-will-be-switched-next-week?linkId=40492041

Probably I will need to check more code in order to determine what could be going wrong, but I have a feeling you might be using an older version that just got deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! it worked.
I had to change the references from V1 to V2 for viewer scripts.

Comment: great, glad it worked. Would you mind marking my answer as the solution.